# Eclipse doesn't have java execution environment for my JDK

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently updated to JDK-21 from 18.0.1.  I compiled some libraries using 21 and started writing some code in eclipse.  I am getting an error that my compiled class is compiled by a later runtime environment.  The problem is that when I go to select my execution environment, there are none that correspond to JDK-21.  Did I miss something here?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 65.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 62.0
```

[image: Installed JREs]

[image: Execution Environments]

Comment: Your Eclipse version is too old, obviously. You can still combine an older execution environment with a newer Java installation. Then, you can’t use newer features but it should run your code with errors.

Comment: To clarify "too old", Java versions 18 and 21 *didn't exist* when the version of Eclipse you are using was released.

Comment: Only Eclipse 2023-09 plus a patch actually has support for Java 21. Eclipse 2023-12 released in December will have support.

Comment: Updating Eclipse AND applying the patch has fixed the issue.  Setting up Apache POI has been a real pain...